# Ubuntu broken when I installed KDE-Plasma

Tags: boot, apt, kde, error-handling

So I installed KDE-Plasma, being the Desktop Environment horde I am, and it was complete crap to what I was used to, so I tried to log out. It didn't log out and just stayed at a black screen with a 'downloading updates' window showing.

I didn't care about the updates, because I was going to be uninstalling it. So I shut down the computer physically. I booted it back up and it gave me a low-graphics warning. I assumed that I would just have to go back in and fix the drivers.

So I click 'Continue in Low-Graphics Mode' and it either brings me to a loading screen forever loading, or a screen that has an empty terminal (once I press the power button on it, it actually starts up- and then it shuts down the PC). I booted into recovery mode and 'fixed broken packages'.

I resumed from recovery mode and it directly brought me to a terminal. I tried the command `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop`and it gave me an error saying that KDE was having an error, and `apt-get -f install` should fix it. So I type in `sudo apt-get -f install` and it loads up and gives me an error about processing the KDE Telepathy Accounts, which is what had an error in the first place.

I am now stuck in an infinite loop of error-repairers having errors. Please help as soon as possible.

*~ Xiphias N.*